# Nodejs async.series not executing all the methods

Tags: node.js

I am trying to use 'async' for my work, so I have written a sample program to make sure that works. async.parallel() works as expected, but not the async.series(). Not sure what I am missing. Can anyone take a look at this sample code and point out the problem/mistake?

async.series([task1, task2]) is just executing 'task1' ONLY.

```
const async = require('async');
var firstThing = function() {
  setTimeout(function(){console.log('IN the First thing')}, 1000);
};

var secondThing = function () {
  setTimeout(function(){console.log('IN the second thing')}, 1500); 
};

async.series(
 [
  firstThing, 
  secondThing
 ],
 function (err, result) {
    console.log('blah blah '+result);
});
```

when I run this code, I get

```
IN the First thing
```

and exits. Why is the second task not being called? what am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: you're missing callbacks.

Comment: Thanks I just made it work ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call back when you finish each of the functions you want to run in series:

```
const async = require('async');
var firstThing = function(callback) {
  setTimeout(function(){console.log('IN the First thing')}, 1000);
  callback(/* pass error or callback*/);
};

var secondThing = function (callback) {
  setTimeout(function(){console.log('IN the second thing')}, 1500); 
  callback(/* pass error or callback*/);
};
```